# Saving file with Japanese characters in Python 3?

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to make a python script that will upload a file to a folder. Everything is working fine except I tried saving a file with a name in Japanese text, and it was cut off. It comes out like somefile__.zip, the underscores being where the Japanese text was. At the top of the file I set coding: utf-8 but this doesn't have any effect. Is it an issue with the secure filename function or am I missing something? My file manager can display files with Japanese characters in the name just fine, so it isn't an issue with that.

```
def upload_file():
if request.method == 'POST': 
    file = request.files['file']
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        if is_image(file.filename):
            filename = shortuuid.uuid()[:7] + "." + file.filename.rsplit(".", 1)[1]
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        else:
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

Comment: What platform are you on? If it's Windows, what's your OEM code page? If it's Unix, what's your default locale? (If it's OS X, just say that and we already know the answer.)

Comment: Adding `coding: utf-8` just affects the encoding used for string literals in your code, like `"."` and `'file'`, which is obviously not  at all relevant to your problem. Please read the [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) and make sure you understand the issues (if you still don't, see the links at the bottom, and the famous [Spotsky blog](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)); just randomly changing things like this is not going to help you.

Comment: Also, where did that `secure_filename` function come from? If it's in your code, show us the code; if it's from some library, tell us which one.

Comment: More importantly, where does `request` come from? What type is it?

Comment: @abarnert secure_filename is from werkzeug utils http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/utils/. As someone already said it looks like it returns an ASCII only string. Damn. I searched for a unicode version of this utility, but nothing came up. How would I even go about writing my own version of it? From the examples provided on the site, it looks like it removes slashes from filenames and replaces spaces with underscores - would just writing a function that does this and spits back out a unicode string be sufficient?

Comment: From the docs, it looks like throwing away all characters but ASCII-compatible, printable, non-special characters is the whole point of this function. If you don't want that, why not just not call it?

Comment: Meanwhile, put that information into the question. Also mention that you're using Django (or, better, use the Django tag). If people have to guess what libraries you're using and what your code is supposed to do, they're liable to guess wrong, or just not bother and skip your question.

Comment: But I need the filename to be secure to prevent attacks on the site.

Comment: Well, that function inherently assumes that any non-ASCII characters are not secure. If you have a different definition of not secure, you can't use that function. You can look at what it does (either in the documentation, which seems very complete and readable, or in the source) and do all the stuff you do want but none of the stuff you don't want, or you can come up with your own notion of "secure filename" and write a function for that yourself, or you can search for something that already exists… but you can't use a function that does the wrong thing just because the name sounds nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure this is right without more info and I would make this a comment but I don't have enough rep yet.

I think you're problem is the `secure_filename` function. I realised this a Django question really. I searched for the secure_filename and found that is from Werkzeug. In the [documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/utils/) it says that the `secure_filename` function returns a ASCII only string. This is probably your problem.

If you remove that function then you can check if it works.

If you really need to make the filename secure you might have to write your own code to do it or find some other library to use.

It also may be that the function is returning an empty filename and so you could use it but it is your responsibility to check that and deal with it.